# Auto-mount 2 HDD with no partitions on startup without losing existing data

Tags: fstab, automount

I am fairly new to Ubuntu but reasonably confident with CLI. I am running 12.04 and have 3 HDD, two with media content that I want to auto-mount on startup. The problem is that they contain 3TB of data each, and I don't want to lose this data in recreating partitions and directories.

The two I want to auto-mount on startup are sdb and sdc - can someone recommend the best way of doing this, either via editing FSTAB or through a GUI? I noted that 12.10 has the option to auto-mount via the disk utility, but when I opted to upgrade to 12.10, I received a warning that my Dell T110 doesnt have a supported graphics card.

Any thoughts please?

```
fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 250.0 GB, 250000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30394 cylinders, total 488281250 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b7bd6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   488280063   243889153    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   488280063   243889152   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdc: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/cambuimedia-root: 247.6 GB, 247560404992 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30097 cylinders, total 483516416 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/cambuimedia-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/cambuimedia-swap_1: 2134 MB, 2134900736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 259 cylinders, total 4169728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/cambuimedia-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Having manually mounted the drives and using the mount command, I get the following:

```
/dev/mapper/cambuimedia-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/cambuimedia/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=cambuimedia)
/dev/sdb on /media/media2 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)
/dev/sdc on /media/media1 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)
```

I had hoped I could just add the last two lines to my fstab file, so it looks like this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/cambuibkup-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=83c8badb-653b-4def-9209-04619def34c9 /boot           ext2    defaults     $
/dev/mapper/cambuibkup-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sdb on /media/media2 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)
/dev/sdc on /media/media1 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)
```

But this doesn't appear to work on reboot?

Comment: Having manually mounted the drives, and using the mount command I get the following:

Answer (score 0):

You can't just copy the `mount` output to fstab. The correct lines would be:

```
/dev/sdb  /media/media2  ext4  rw,nosuid,nodev  0  0
/dev/sdc  /media/media1  ext4  rw,nosuid,nodev  0  0
```

or similar (the last number would be 2 if you want the filesystem checked at mount time, see `man 5 fstab`). See the comment line in /etc/fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
```

So your fstab is trying to mount the device `/dev/sdb` on the directory `on` which will not exists...

---

PS why do you use unpartitioned drives? Probably it's not a problem but sounds *odd*.

Comment: It is very unusual not to partition a drive. It is then just one jumbo floppy drive. Not sure even if it can be mounted as almost all tools expect partitions. Did see one user who seemed to be showing a loop mount, or may floppy will work?

Comment: `mount`, and so the fstab way, shouldn't have problems (they can mount it manually, after all). But I agree that will confuse a lot of tools... I used to do that when flash drives where small, and stopped that when some tool decided that the thing was "virgin" and proceeded to format it.